# PHP page with json collected data dont work on ubuntu same work on windows server

Tags: php, mysql, json, ubuntu

As i am new to this part forgive me if problem is simple .

test enviroment is on win7 and WAMP 2.5 and there is no problem for data.php page to collect data from mysql.

prod. enviroment is on ubuntu 15.04 and installed php5 apache2 mysql5.x...

all parts of site is working(there is one page with table that showing same info as data.php work fine) only data.php that collect data from mysql is not working ...that make me supose that problem is in json part

```
<?php
#Include the connect.php file
include('Connections/mysql.php');
#Connect to the database
//connection String
$connect = mysql_connect($hostname_mysql, $username_mysql, $password_mysql)
or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
//Select The database
$bool = mysql_select_db($database_mysql, $connect);
if ($bool === False){
   print "can't find $database";
}
// get data and store in a json array
$query = "SELECT * FROM informacije";

if (isset($_GET['update']))
{
        // UPDATE COMMAND
        $update_query = "UPDATE `informacije` SET `Ime`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Ime'])."',
        `Kompanija`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Kompanija'])."',
        `Domacin`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Domacin'])."',
        `dand`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['dand'])."',
        `dano`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['dano'])."',
        `hotel`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['hotel'])."',
        `Notes`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Notes'])."',
         `vremed`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['vremed'])."',
                `vremeo`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['vremeo'])."',
                        `nedelja`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['nedelja'])."'
         WHERE `ID`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ID'])."'";
         $result = mysql_query($update_query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysql_error());
     echo $result;
}
else
{
    // SELECT COMMAND
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $employees[] = array(
                        'ID' => $row['ID'],
                        'Ime' => $row['Ime'],
                        'Kompanija' => $row['Kompanija'],
                        'Domacin' => $row['Domacin'],
                        'dand' => $row['dand'],
                        'dano' => $row['dano'],
                        'hotel' => $row['hotel'],
                        'Notes' => $row['Notes'],
                        'vremed' => $row['vremed'],
                        'vremeo' => $row['vremeo'],
                        'nedelja' => $row['nedelja']

                  );
        }

        echo json_encode($employees);
}
?>
```

please advise

Comment: Question is unclear also if problem is in json part then show the code of that part also. please show full code.thanks

Comment: Hi, first thanks on fast answer, i have use this article to create editablle table on one page. http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-grid-cells-editing-with-php-and-mysql/

Comment: and on windows wamp enviroment works normaly but on ubuntu table is empty. also when go to data.php blank page is shown in explorer . hope that now i was more acurate now :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. field 'updated' (datetime when row is las time updated) deleted from code and now works, that was edited after upload to prod. env. but forgot on it compleatly

Dejan